# Regex to allow only numbers and only one comma (not prefix or postfix comma)

Tags: regex

I am using regex method to check that string contains only numbers and just one comma and accept (not prefix or postfix)

EX-> 123,456  Accepted

EX-> ,123456 NOT accepted

EX-> 123456, NOT accepted

I am using below regex but it does not work, it allows to repeat commas and only works for prefix commas

```
[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: You could consider using lookarounds `(?<!,)\b[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*\b(?!,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern to test a full string:

```
^[0-9]+,?[0-9]*\b$
```

Here, the comma is optional, but since the "last" digits are optional too, I added a word boundary to ensure that the comma doesn't end the string. (a word boundary fails between a comma and the end of the string.)

Answer (score 1):

To allow a single comma and not match when surrounded a comma, you could make use of a word boundary and lookarounds (if supported) to assert not a comma to the left and the right.

```
(?<!,)\b[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)?\b(?!,)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB5eog/1)

If the numbers are the only string, you can use anchors to assert the start and the end of the string.

```
^\d+(?:\,\d+)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZ046J/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this : \b\d+,\d+\b

with this expression all the matches will contain only one coma but the coma is not optional in this case.